# How to escape whitespace in SonarQube configuration file?

Tags: properties, sonarqube5.1

Does anyone know how to escape whitespace in a sonar-project.properties file so that SonarQube understands the property correctly. In my case, it is an Xcode project and for some reason the project has .xcodeproj file of the form "A B.xcodeproj" where A and B are two words. Is there a way I can specify this without having to create symbolic links or aliases to this .xcodeproj file to make SonarQube runner happy? I tried escaping with backslash () between the words, double quote and single quote around the whole property but no luck.

Thanks,

Paddy

Comment: Escaping the whitespace with a backslash should do it. Which property is this for and what error are you getting ?

Comment: This is for the name of the .xcodeproj property for an Xcode project. Using backslash is not helping either. For example if it "A B.xcodeproj" then if I use A\ B.xcodeproj then it picks it as B.codeproj